# How do I calculate the average number of divisors in Java

Tags: java, average

I'm making a program that contains the method `numdiv` which finds the number of divisors of `d`. I also have a method called `sumSquares` which finds the squares between 1 and `n`. I've put a for loop in the main method to find sum of squares and divisors of 10 through 50, only now I want to find the average number of divisors b/w 10 and 50. Here's the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("NUMBER\tSUM OF SQUARES\tDIVISORS");//setup table
        //loop through numbers 10 to 50
        for(int i = 10; i <= 50; i++){ //i represents the integers to print
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + sumSquares(i) + "\t\t" + numdiv(i));
        }
    }

    public static int sumSquares(int n){
        int sum = 0; //define sum
        for(int num = 1; num <= n; num++){
            sum = (num*num) + sum; //set sum equal to num*num then add to sum
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int numdiv(int d){
        int div = 0; //counter for divisors

        for(int num = 1; num <= d; num++){
            if(d % num == 0){ //check if d is a divisor
                div++; //increment div each time true
            }
        }
        return div;
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea of how I can do that please?

Comment: Add one more loop. Calculate `numdiv` for ints in [10, 50], sum them and divide by 41

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Also, if you're wondering, the way to calculate the average in a set of numbers, then add them all up and divide them by the number of them. For example: `int[] nums = {70, 79, 79};` `average = 228/*<- Sum of numbers in the array*//nums.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your methods, without changing them to keep your logic, you can change your `main` method to be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("NUMBER\tSUM OF SQUARES\tDIVISORS");//setup table
    //loop through numbers 10 to 50
    int sumSquares = 0;
    int numDiv = 0;
    int totalSquares = 0;
    int totalDiv = 0;
    for(int i = 10; i <= 50; i++){ //i represents the integers to print
        sumSquares = sumSquares(i);
        numDiv = numdiv(i);
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + sumSquares + "\t\t" + numDiv);
        totalSquares += sumSquares;
        totalDiv += numDiv;
    }
    System.out.printf("Average sumSquares: %d - Average numDiv: %d", totalSquares/41, totalDiv/41);
}
```

**Note**: I've hardcoded the 41 divisor because you have the numbers between 10 and 50 harcoded as well. You should externalize this and also you `for` loop numbers.